# Python matplotlib time series plot -- show years on x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

The Python code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
xx["SPY"].plot()
plt.show()
```

where xx is a data frame with a date index produces a time series plot where the dates 11/30/2010, 9/15/2011, 7/2/2012 etc. are shown as labels on the x axis. I would like to labels corresponding to years, so that only "2010", "2011", "2012" etc. are shown on the x axis. How can this be done?

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#date-tickers and http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo1.html

Comment: Thanks, I was able to run the script at the 2nd link, which does what I want.